# every abelian scheme quotient of a Picard scheme?

Tags: abelian-schemes, ag.algebraic-geometry

Is every abelian scheme $\mathcal{A}/X$ under suitable conditions on $X$ a quotient of a Picard scheme of a curve $\mathcal{C}/X$? I need it for $X/\mathbf{F}_q$ smooth projective.

Comment: something related : in "Algebraic Groups and Class Fields" (J.P Serre), it is proved (VII.13) that on a algebraically closed field,
every abelian variety is isomorphic to the quotient of a product of jacobians (of curves) by a connected subgroup.

Comment: Yes, I know this, but what I really need is Abelian *schemes*.

Comment: See also http://modular.math.washington.edu/edu/Fall2003/252/lectures/10-17-03/10-17-03.pdf

Comment: and http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AV.pdf p. 116.

Comment: Does your definition of abelian schemes include "projective over $X$"? This at least is necessary. (I assume that by "curve" you mean "smooth proper curve").

Comment: As far as I see from the literature, the question is not settled already if `$X$` is the spectrum of a finite field.

Comment: @Matthieu: it is true over finite fields. The proof, as in the classical case, relies on Bertini's theorem over finite fields and it is proved by Gabber and by Poonen's around 2000.

Comment: @Timo: the statement should hold over local (maybe noetherian) rings because Bertini's theorem is true in this case.


Comment: Liu, good point! Of course Poonen's Bertini theorems involve sections with hypersurfaces of large degree. I thought that in the classical proof that abelian varieties are quotients of jacobians, it was important to cut by hyperplanes. Now that I think about it again, I see that it is not.

Comment: I doubt that this is true for some ring of integers in a number field, where Bertini's theorem fails. But you're happy to exclude this case.

Answer (score 1):

Let me sketch an idea why *there are not enough Jacobians*. At some points I have asked for references/proofs in []. Edit: Didn't work out as hoped.

Comment: The Kodaira-Parshin construction produces lots of non-isotrivial proper and smooth curves over a smooth projective curve. See for example M. Martin-Deschamps, Astérisque vol. 127 (1985).

Comment: also, the complement of a divisor has no reason to be affine -- take $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \setminus 0 \times \mathbb{P}^1 = \mathbb{A}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. 

Comment: $M_{g,n}$ is very far from being affine. For every $g\geq 3$, there is a complete curve passing through any point. This follows from the existence of a compactification with boundary of codimension >1 (the Satake compactification). The problem is only the complement of a very ample divisor is guaranteed to be affine.
